# my sql update by checking two columns data

Tags: mysql

`UPDATE city_final SET city_final.distance=500000,  where city_final.fromcountryID =1 and  city_final.tocountryID!=1`

I want to update `distance =500000` by checking `countryID` to and from columns
what is the error of thids query

Answer (score 3):

Remove comma after `city_final.distance=500000`

```
UPDATE city_final 
SET city_final.distance=500000
where city_final.fromcountryID =1 and city_final.tocountryID!=1
```